# Flatbuffers: table bool value set with byte instead of bool

Tags: flatbuffers

My table, when compiled for go, ends up using GetByte and PrependByteSlot instead of the Bool alternative (GetBool, PrependBoolSlot).

Is there anything I can do to change that?
If not, where can I find confirmation that the byte will be equal to 0 or 1 (false/true)?

Here's a table showing this exact behaviour:

```
table BooleanContent {
  value:bool = false;
}
```

Here's the generated file:

```
// Code generated by the FlatBuffers compiler. DO NOT EDIT.

package GatewayProtocol

import (
    flatbuffers "github.com/google/flatbuffers/go"
)

type BooleanContent struct {
    _tab flatbuffers.Table
}

func GetRootAsBooleanContent(buf []byte, offset flatbuffers.UOffsetT) *BooleanContent {
    n := flatbuffers.GetUOffsetT(buf[offset:])
    x := &BooleanContent{}
    x.Init(buf, n+offset)
    return x
}

func (rcv *BooleanContent) Init(buf []byte, i flatbuffers.UOffsetT) {
    rcv._tab.Bytes = buf
    rcv._tab.Pos = i
}

func (rcv *BooleanContent) Table() flatbuffers.Table {
    return rcv._tab
}

func (rcv *BooleanContent) Value() byte {
    o := flatbuffers.UOffsetT(rcv._tab.Offset(4))
    if o != 0 {
        return rcv._tab.GetByte(o + rcv._tab.Pos)
    }
    return 0
}

func (rcv *BooleanContent) MutateValue(n byte) bool {
    return rcv._tab.MutateByteSlot(4, n)
}

func BooleanContentStart(builder *flatbuffers.Builder) {
    builder.StartObject(1)
}
func BooleanContentAddValue(builder *flatbuffers.Builder, value byte) {
    builder.PrependByteSlot(0, value, 0)
}
func BooleanContentEnd(builder *flatbuffers.Builder) flatbuffers.UOffsetT {
    return builder.EndObject()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Booleans are certainly stored as a byte in the FlatBuffers binary format, but there is no reason it can't convert it to boolean upon access, as happens in other languages.

So this may well be a bug in Go code generator, I'd file an issue on github, tagged by [Go].

Comment: Done, thx for the feedback. [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/google/flatbuffers/issues/5220)